# Can Get-ACL show Exact "ActiveDirectoryRight"?

Tags: active-directory, security, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, access-control-list

I am trying to obtain permission list from OUs, and have been using "Get-ACL";

```
(Get-Acl $OUName).access | Select Identityreference,ActiveDirectoryRights,accesscontroltype
```

The result is not satisfactory showing lot of "ReadProperty" and "WriteProperty" permissions and obfuscating what the exact property name on the background is. Is there a way to get the exact property name with "Get-ACL"?

Let me know if any extra questions or confirmation needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already discovered, the property types and permissions you're looking for are represented by GUIDs, in the ObjectType and InheritedObjectType properties of each ActiveDirectoryAccessRule.

To resolve these GUIDs to human-readable format involves the AD Schema (for object types) and the Configuration partition (for Extended rights), looking up the schemaIDGUID/rightsGUID and its display name.

Long story short, this sample script probably has enough info to get what you're looking for:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Active-Directory-OU-1d09f989

Lines 50-53 essentially build the Hash tables that will allow the GUID -> Display name lookup.